# OpenERP: Complex interactive search across several objects/tables - how?

Tags: search, odoo, wizard, transient

Are Wizards & Transient Models the right way to implement complex interactive search across several tables (objects) and to visualize data aggregated from several objects?

**“Complex interactive search”** means a search panel with several input fields for entering search criteria, where input fields are dynamically filtered according to user access rules and data from other fields.

**“Across several tables”** means data stored in different objects `(osv.Model)` -- i.e. not only in different tables, but in different python `'objects' (osv.Model)`.

---

My current implementation using wizards & transients has the following drawbacks:

- no way of filtering / grouping search results. Search results are handled as a one2many field, displayed as a Tree view in the Form view of the parent search wizard ==> hence no way of grouping results inside a form view of a wizard. Frankly, I’d be happy if there would be a way of making a complex search over multiple objects from a Tree view, as we do it with simple search on a single object.
- 2 reloads of a page happen when changing input parameters and making another search. First, the page is refreshed with the old results inside, and then after a second or two (w/o showing “Loading…”) the page is refreshed with the new results appearing. This doesn’t happen if I search with the same parameters several times in a row -- then only 1 refresh happens. This double refresh is very user-unfriendly, as it creates an impression that the search failed (the old results are displayed). Probably, this happens because on every search I create a new wizard instance (to keep a search history before it’s cleared with autovacuum) and return its id as a `'res_id'`. However, I create a copy of previous wizard by passing an empty list as default search results ids, so I wouldn’t expect the old-results to show up. Also, I wouldn’t expect the second refresh to happen.
- results from all previous searches are preserved on the client side and just made hidden on the page instead of being removed completely from the page ===> makes the page heavy after a lot of searches. E.g.:

  ```
  <div class="oe_view_manager oe_view_manager_inline" style="display: none;">
  <div class="oe_view_manager oe_view_manager_inline" style="display: none;">
  <div class="oe_view_manager oe_view_manager_inline" style="display: none;">
  <div class="oe_view_manager oe_view_manager_inline">
  ```

Here: 3 old result sets + the current active one (visible). Think I can get rid of those old results using JavaScript. Still, I wonder what is the purpose of such preserve&hide behavior?